# Wrong SPARQL query - using Java

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am trying to make this very interesting query pointing at DBpedia.org
I am new into Java, and this SPARQL is my first step in that direction.

I have figured out to make something like this code. It's modified from what I could find googleing;
From the source I could get the abstract from a single query. Now I want to get all the properties that you can see in the query string here, and more.

Can someone please help me get this working? I am stuck. Thank you!

```
String service = "PREFIX rdfs: http://dbpedia.org/page/Texas_Longhorn";
String query = "SELECT * WHERE {"
        + " rdfs:name ?name ;"
        + " rdfs:label ?label ;"
        + " rdfs:abstract ?abstract ."
        + "}";

QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service, query);
try {
    ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

    for (; results.hasNext();) {

        QuerySolution sol = (QuerySolution) results.next();

        System.out.println(sol.get("?name"));
        System.out.println(sol.get("?label"));            
        System.out.println(sol.get("?abstract"));


    }
}catch(Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
   qe.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your SPARQL query is totally wrong. When you have SPARQL, you look for triple and if you look at your first line you only see two elements. Then, there is no such thing as `rdfs:name` and `rdfs:abstract` in dbpedia. And `rdfs` is a predefined namespace and you better keep it to help you with the labels. You have `dbpedia-owl:abstract` and `foaf:name`. So your query has to be:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
     ?x foaf:name ?name ;
     rdfs:label ?label ;
     dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .
    }
```

However, in this case `?name` and `?label` would result in the same variable. So I would edit your query to:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
     ?x rdfs:label ?label ;
     dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides making the changes that @Artemis suggested, you also need to change the `service` String to dbpedia's endpoint:

`String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";`

[`QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QueryExecutionFactory.html) accepts a String parameter representing the SPARQL endpoint (service), and a query, defined as either Jena Query or String.